# how to convert character to string in xml for displaying in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

This the XML file:

```
<ROOT>
    <R FN="Ganapati" LN="Jena" Com="PC"  />
    <R FN="Chandra" LN="Reddy" Com="PC"/>
    <R FN="Charn" LN="Raj" Com="PC"/>
    <R FN="Sunil" LN="Kumar" Com="PC"/>
    <R FN="Muni" LN="Kiran" Com="PC"/>
    <R FN="Raghu" LN="Kiran" Com="PC"/>
    <R FN="Suresh" LN="Kiran" Com="PC"/>
    <R FN="Naresh" LN="Kiran" Com="PC"/>
    <R FN="Ranjith" LN="Kiran" Com="PC"/>
</ROOT>
```

Note how it says `Com="PC"` in the code. I want to display "Point Cloud" instead, so how should I map this in ExtJS?

This is my ExtJS code:

```
        {name: 'FN',mapping:'@FN'},
        { name: 'LN',mapping:'@LN'},
        { name: 'Com',mapping:'@Com'}              
    ])
});

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {header: "FN", width: 120, dataIndex: 'FN'},
        {header: "LN", width: 100, dataIndex: 'LN'},
        {header: "Com", width: 115, dataIndex: 'Com'}
    ],

    // ...
});
```

Comment: try `renderer` in column http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a renderer like this:

```
function renderCom(val, metadata, record) {
    if (val == "PC") {
        return "Point Cloud";
    } else if ( val == "SE") {
        return "Something Else";
    } else {
        return val; // if nothing matches return the original value
    }
}

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
store: store,
columns: [
    {header: "FN", width: 120, dataIndex: 'FN'},
   {header: "LN", width: 100, dataIndex: 'LN'},
    {header: "Com", width: 115, dataIndex: 'Com', renderer: renderCom}

],
```